# Why is this code not working with .... jquery

Tags: jquery

Hey why is my code not working with jquery versions. My code seems not to work when to jquery files are present here is the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

The script seems not to fire correctly. Here is the script:

```
var timer;

$(".icon-menu-2").animate({ width: "200", "margin-right": "30", queue: false, duration: "slow"});
$(".c_right").animate({ "margin-right": "215", queue: false, duration: "slow"}, function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".icon-menu-2").animate({ "margin-right": "-155", queue: false, duration: "slow"});
        $(".c_right").animate({ "margin-right": "30", queue: false, duration: "slow"});
    }, 500);
});
```

Does anybody know why my code is not being accepted by jquery 1.5.2 and 1.10.1.min ? How can I correct my code?

Comment: Why are you including 1.5.2 and then immediately 1.10.1... that makes no sense.

Comment: I need them for a history script that I have. I want to rewrite the code to accommodate both scripts

Comment: yea about that... remove one.

Comment: Like @JamesMontagne pointed out, drop one of the `jquery` files, you can't use both.

Comment: If you really *must* have two versions of jQuery (you have an outdated plugin that breaks in anything but 1.5.2), use jQuery's [no conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use the developer tools with your web browser to see what scripts are actually being loaded.

For example, if you are using Google Chrome, open the HTML page which declares the JQuery scripts, press F12 to open Developer Tools, then click on 'Resources', then in the 'Frames' folder you will be able to see which scripts have actually been loaded into memory.

In the 'Sources' tab, click on the web page source code and it should highlight any errors being thrown. If you aren't sure what they mean, append them to your question and then we can help you figure out how to fix them.

But looking at what you provided us, it seems you are loading in two versions of JQuery. This won't work. You can either load in one or the other, but not both. If both are successfully loaded into memory, calls to JQuery methods would likely fail as the browser won't know which methods to call, since there are two different versions of the same methods.

As Nick points out above, if you really have to use both scripts, use the JQuery No-Conflict mode.